# Can Surahs be read half in prayer and the other half through the Quran

Tags: quran-recitation, surah

My mother intends to recite Surah Bakharah on an everyday basis. So her question is, with the same intention of reciting it everyday (with also the intention of receiving barakah), can she recite half of it in her tahajjud and the rest through the Quran. Is this allowed?

Or is it necessary to get the benefit of reciting Surah Bakharah it must be done through the Quran only.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. I'm a bit unclear about the focus of your question, is it whether your mother can or not split the recitation of surat al-Baqarah between recitation from a moshaf and prayer, or whether the rewards of reciting this surah only comes from recitation from a moshaf?

Answer (score -1):

yes she can recite half of it in her tahajjud and the rest through the Quran
no problem in that

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this answer, e.g. by adding references?  See [How do I add evidence to my answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer)